# Efficiency of sharing an integer variable

Tags: performance, compression

First of all, sorry for my English, I'm not a native speaker. That said, I've lately been working on some programs to compress string data into integer values, using the Huffman's tree structure. The compressed data is meant to be shared using LoRa from a board to another.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know if compressing the data is more efficient, because I've now converted successfully a char into a unique integer code, but the code, in some extreme cases, is a 5-digit number. So I don't know if it's more efficient to send a char value or an integer value.

Basically, I'm trying to understand if communication byte by byte is more efficient than communication char by char, and if so, by how much.

I've tried searching if this question is a duplicate, but the only thing I've found is that for the CPU it's better to work with integers.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your "5 digit number" is all zeros and ones. In order to compress, each digits becomes a single bit in your data stream. You pack the bits, eight at a time, into bytes. So eight 5-bit values are packed into five bytes.

Comment: No that's the problem, 5 digits is the integer to convert in binary

Comment: You need to provide code and input and output examples. Your English is fine, but your question is very unclear.